# Data Generation Plan Missing from VS2010 Pro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was following this tutorial

http://nepomucenobr.com.br/blog/post/Generating-e2809cdummy-datae2809d-with-Visual-Studio.aspx

and I got to the point where I am should add a data generation plan file. Yet when I click on the folder there is not data generation plan file. I don't know why. Do I have to install it separately or what?

Or is it because I am using 2005 express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833237.aspx

Data generation plans are apparently only available with VS Premium and Ultimate.

Comment: Mine is VS 2010 Ultimate, but missing Data Generation Plan too.